# Python issue: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python

I got following error message when I run python xxx.py. How to fix it, many thanks.

> c:\Python27>python xxx.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test.py", line 34, in 
>       print player(1,0,10)
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

following is xxx.py:

```
def create(pos=[0,0]):
    def player(dir_x,dir_y,step):
        new_x = pos[0] + dir_x*step 
        new_y = pos[1] + dir_y*step
        pos[0] = new_x  
        pos[1] = new_y
        return pos
return player

if __name__ == '__main__':  
player = create()
    print player(1,0,10)
    print player(0,1,20)
    print player(-1,0,10)
```

Comment: What are you doing??? `return player`? What happens to you indent?

Comment: Your indentation is screwed

Comment: Indentation is a crucial part of Python syntax. You question cannot be answered until you fix the indentation, which is clearly incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code except your indentation. Correct is:

```
def create(pos=[0,0]):
    def player(dir_x,dir_y,step):
        new_x = pos[0] + dir_x*step 
        new_y = pos[1] + dir_y*step
        pos[0] = new_x  
        pos[1] = new_y
        return pos
    return player

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    player = create()
    print player(1,0,10)
    print player(0,1,20)
    print player(-1,0,10)
```

which prints:

```
[10, 0]
[10, 20]
[0, 20]
```

Comment: Sorry, this is just copy/paste issue from mine. my real coding is same as your mention without indentation problem, unfortunatly the error is:

  File "test.py", line 32, in <module>
    print player(1,0,10)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: That error does not appear when using the code exactly as is. You need to update your question if you are using a different code than the one provided

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's truely indentation problem I missed. Thanks for your kindly help.